# URL Hack for pre-populating field not working on Experience Cloud Site

Tags: related-list, urlhacking

I'm using the following code for URL Hack:

```
/lightning/o/customObject__c/new?&amp;navigationLocation=RELATED_LIST&amp;recordId={!customObject__c.Id}&amp;defaultFieldValues=customField__c={!customObject__c.Id}
```

- The button for this URL is located at a related list object.
- It pre-populates the 'customField__c' field with 'customObject__c.Id' field's value.
- In Lightning / Classic it's working fine, however not working in the Experience Site.

**What I've tried:**

- Since, I couldn't figure out the URL for Experience Cloud site, I've tried the following URL:

  **{!URLFOR( $Action.customObject__c.New , null, [customField__c=customObject__c.Id])}**
- It opens the Pop-up but doesn't pre-populate the fields.

Comment: Have you tried with NavigationMixin instead of URL hacking?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_default

It passes in the state the defaultFieldsValues.

Comment: I'm using default UI, without any lwc/custom components.